# LLVM XRay on Android

Tags: clang, llvm, clang++

I am trying to get the clang Android toolchain compiled with XRay support.

1. I managed to compile the clang Android toolchain with XRay (`defines[COMPILER_RT_BUILD_XRAY]= ON` in base_builders.py)
2. in my Android.bp I do :

```
cflags: [
  ......
  "-fxray-instrument",
  "-fxray-instruction-threshold=1",
  ....
],
cppflags: [
  ......
  "-fxray-instrument",
  "-fxray-instruction-threshold=1",
  ....
],
ldflags: [
  ......
  "-fxray-instrument",
  "-fxray-instruction-threshold=1",
  ....
],
....
```

3. if I ommit the XRay related `ldflags`, I can compile the executables just fine, but then there's no XRay tracing (XRay prints some messages when it works and also it dumps out a trace file)
4. if I have the `ldflags` on, I get :

```
libclang_rt.xray-aarch64-android.a: No such file or directory
libclang_rt.xray-basic-aarch64-android.a: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas ?